# php like concat get userid with username

Tags: php, mysqli

I am creating PHP user details display script I have added userid to Like Conact method but i want to add userid and username to it's two parameters

Here is my code

```
if(isset($_GET["user_id"]))
{
$uid = $_GET["user_id"];
}
if ($stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT p.*, c.cat_title,u.username,u.profile_pic,u.
content_details,u.web_link,u.fb_page,
u.github,u.twit_link,title,desc1,time,img,
views,id FROM products AS p 
JOIN users AS u ON u.user_id= p.user_id
JOIN category AS c ON c.cat_id = p.cat_id
WHERE u.user_id LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')  ")){
$stmt->bind_param("s", $uid);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you indent your code? It would help with readability, not only for you, but also for us.

Comment: So you want to take userid and username and make it look like this basically? %1muusername%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE u.user_id LIKE CONCAT('%',?,?,'%')")){
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $uid, $username);
```

Is this what you were asking for? Based on your question this would do it. If you're trying to do LIKE by either or then you'll have to use OR and do another LIKE comparison.